# javascript code does not execute after a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code (snippet from a larger function):

```
var res = data.results;
for (var i=0;i<res.length;i++) {
    $('<option value="' + res[i] + '">' + res[i] + '</option>').appendTo(sel);
}
if (data.select && data.select!='') { sel.val(data.select); }
```

For some reason, the

```
if (data.select && data.select!='') { sel.val(data.select); }
```

line just wasn't executing, and is appearing greyed out in Firebug suggesting that Firebug somehow knows it is not reachable.  If I make a simple change to the code like this:

```
var res = data.results;
for (var i=0;i<res.length;i++) {
    var opt = '<option value="' + res[i] + '">' + res[i] + '</option>';
    $(opt).appendTo(sel);
}
if (data.select && data.select!='') { sel.val(data.select); }
```

the last line runs without issue.

I found similar post on here where the for loop had a <= for the while parameter causing an error and although this is not the case here, when I stepped through the code it was trying to execute the loop one more time than it should have, i.e. if res.length was 4, it was allowing i to increment to 4 and then trying to execute the code in the loop which was therefore ending the code because res[i] was out of range, even though it wasn't placing an error in the console.  If I change the code as demonstrated, the loop does not run when i == res.length

So, how did Firebug know that the original code wasn't going to allow execution past the end of the loop, and why is the loop executing one more time than it should?

The entire function is below and is a success callback from a jQuery ajax call which populates a select with the values received from the server:

```
function GetDeptsOK(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    var sel = $('#orgpicker').find('select[name="orgpicker-dept"]');
    if (sel.length == 0) {
        var cell = $('#orgpicker-deptcell');
        cell.text('');
        $('<select name="orgpicker-dept"></select>').appendTo(cell);
        sel = $('#orgpicker').find('select[name="orgpicker-dept"]');
    } else {
        sel.find('option').remove();
    }
    $('<option value=""></option>').appendTo(sel);
    var res = data.results;
    for (var i=0;i<res.length;i++) {
        $('<option value="' + res[i] + '">' + res[i] + '</option>').appendTo(sel);
    }
    if (data.select && data.select!='') { sel.val(data.select); }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the debugger (Firebug is quite good for Firefox)?

Comment: Yes, I am using Firebug. Thanks.

Comment: It usually happens if the term can never be reached.

Answer (score 1):

replace this by

```
var res = data.results;
for (var i=0;i<res.length;i++) {
    if(!res[i])
       break;
    var opt = '<option value="' + res[i] + '">' + res[i] + '</option>';
    $(opt).appendTo(sel);
}
if (data.select && data.select!='') { sel.val(data.select); }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but surely I should have to test for res[i] being valid because the for loop shouldn't execute if i==res.length? My question was more to do with why the loop was executing if i==4 and res.length==4.